# PHP newbie - script not working to send email with form contents

Tags: php, forms

I am very new with PHP and the script I need to use to send an order form to my email address is not working.

I have literally built this from the ground up with an online tutorial that was raved about, but it won't work for me at all. I also tried Googling solutions with no luck. Any ideas?

```
<?php

$cases = $_POST['cases'];
$other_cases = $_POST['other_cases'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$business_name = $_POST['business_name'];
$bill_address = $_POST['bill_address'];
$bill_city = $_POST['bill_city'];
$bill_state = $_POST['bill_state'];
$bill_zip = $_POST['bill_zip'];
$ship_address = $_POST['ship_address'];
$ship_city = $_POST['ship_city'];
$ship_state = $_POST['ship_state'];
$ship_zip = $_POST['ship_zip'];
$additional = $_POST['additional'];



$from = 'From: TC Body Bag Order Form';
$to = 'heather@featherhart.com';
$subject = 'You have a new order!';

$body = "Full Name: $full_name\n 
         Email Address: $email\n 
         Phone Number: $phone\n
         Cases: $cases\n
         Other Amount: $other_cases\n 
         Business Name: $business_name\n 
         Billing Line 1: $bill_address\n 
         Billing Line 2: $bill_city\n, $bill_state\n $bill_zip\n 
         Shipping Line 1: $ship_address\n 
         Shipping Line 2: $ship_city, $ship_state $ship_zip\n 
         Additional: $additional\n ";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your order has been placed! You will receive an email 
                shortly with an updated total and confirmation of your order.</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Oops... something went wrong!<br>
                Please try again.</p>'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Does it show any errors, or maybe the "Oops" message? Any output at all?

Comment: Your missing a closing bracket, also its a good idea to check and validate user inputted data. You won't want lots of empty emails when it does finally send

Comment: Have you tried changing your $from to $headers?  $from may be misinterpreted by the function simply because of the name of the string.

Comment: I'm receiving an the "Oops" error I included at the bottom of the script. After changing $from to $headers I am still receiving the error message. I'm stumped as to what could be wrong!

Comment: I will add in the closing bracket, which I actually deleted right before I added it in, thinking it was extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// The message
 $message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
 // Send
mail('mail@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

.as I see there is no problem in your code.

-You have to try to send mail with very basic code like the previous code. If it's ok and email have been sent successfully, then you have to debug and check if all variables have been set or not using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

this would print post array and see if all variable is ok or not.

for professional way you can use this one to check if variable is set or not:

```
$cases = isset($_POST['cases']) ? $_POST['cases'] : ""
```

instead of this one

```
$cases = $_POST['cases'];
```

:) enjoy